# Nginx Load Balancing Upstream proxy

Tags: tomcat, nginx, docker, webserver

I need some help in nginx Load balancing.
I have a docker instance which is serving a static web page, which have two containers for that
Let say
192.168.1.1:8081 -> serving a static page 
192.168.1.1:8082 -> serving same static page

Now what i want is to load balance these two sites with Nginx.
when i enter these IP address 192.168.1.1 ,these Ip have to serve the load between my two sites.

In my Nginx i have to set two files for that

Nginx.conf ,in these file I have to include my default.conf file .
default.conf file has the following information.

```
upstream mynewsite {

        server 192.168.1.1:8081;
        server 192.168.1.1:8082;       
}

server {
listen 80; # I tried by commenting with these also
server_name  192.168.1.1;
#server_name mynewsite; # I tried like this also
index index.htm index.html index.php; 
access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log ;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

location / {
        proxy_pass http://mynewsite;
        }
```

when I type 192.168.1.1:8081 , I am able to access the page from my first docker container.
And when I type 192.168.1.1:8082 , I am able to access the page from my second docker container.

But when I type 192.168.1.1 , I am unable to access the page.

I am using Centos 6.8 and nginx version: nginx/1.10.2, 
Docker version 1.7.1
Tomcat application server on my docker container.
Note://192.168.1.1 is not the exact ip, I used some other Ip
Any Suggestions to fix this issue.
Thanks,
Ganesh

Answer (score 0):

Start small, check your logs, then go from there, maybe none of the upstreams can be reached by nginx:

```
server {
listen 80;
  location / {
        proxy_pass http://mynewsite;
        }
}

upstream mynewsite {

        server 192.168.1.1:8081;
        server 192.168.1.1:8082;       
}
```